# MVC cant find the correct view when model is a string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm having trouble getting my action to find and return the correct view.

It's in the `Account` Area, in the `AccountController`, and the view is `ConfirmAccount.cshtml.` It takes a model of `string`.

I have tried these:

A)    I tried just passing in the model like normal, with the view name matching the action name.

```
    public ActionResult ConfirmAccount(string id)
    {
        return View(id);
    }
```

This didn't seem to work since the model is a string, it just tried to find a string with the name of id.

B) So I tried specifying the view name, hoping it would find the ConfirmAccount view, and understand id is the model.

```
    public ActionResult ConfirmAccount(string id)
    {
        return View("ConfirmAccount", id);
    }
```

The results of this one confused me, It tried to find the following:

> ~/Areas/Account/Views/Account/ConfirmAccount.aspx
>   ~/Areas/Account/Views/Account/ConfirmAccount.ascx
>   ~/Areas/Account/Views/Shared/ConfirmAccount.aspx
>   ~/Areas/Account/Views/Shared/ConfirmAccount.ascx
>   ~/Views/Account/ConfirmAccount.aspx
>   ~/Views/Account/ConfirmAccount.ascx ~/Views/Shared/ConfirmAccount.aspx
>   ~/Views/Shared/ConfirmAccount.ascx
>   ~/Areas/Account/Views/Account/xNMf1HNl_2pLp-6MXpXl3g2If.master
>   ~/Areas/Account/Views/Shared/xNMf1HNl_2pLp-6MXpXl3g2If.master
>   ~/Views/Account/xNMf1HNl_2pLp-6MXpXl3g2If.master
>   ~/Views/Shared/xNMf1HNl_2pLp-6MXpXl3g2If.master
>   ~/Areas/Account/Views/Account/xNMf1HNl_2pLp-6MXpXl3g2If.cshtml
>   ~/Areas/Account/Views/Account/xNMf1HNl_2pLp-6MXpXl3g2If.vbhtml
>   ~/Areas/Account/Views/Shared/xNMf1HNl_2pLp-6MXpXl3g2If.cshtml
>   ~/Areas/Account/Views/Shared/xNMf1HNl_2pLp-6MXpXl3g2If.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Account/xNMf1HNl_2pLp-6MXpXl3g2If.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Account/xNMf1HNl_2pLp-6MXpXl3g2If.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/xNMf1HNl_2pLp-6MXpXl3g2If.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/xNMf1HNl_2pLp-6MXpXl3g2If.vbhtml

Where it's looking for the aspx / ascx pages would be perfect if it was looking for the cshtml pages there, but for some reason it's not and instead tries to find the cs/vbshtml pages by the id. Does anyone know why this is happening?

C) The third and only other thing I could think of, was to specify the controller name as well.

```
    public ActionResult ConfirmAccount(string id)
    {
        return View("ConfirmAccount", "Account", id);
    }
```

> ~/Areas/Account/Views/Account/ConfirmAccount.aspx
>   ~/Areas/Account/Views/Account/ConfirmAccount.ascx
>   ~/Areas/Account/Views/Shared/ConfirmAccount.aspx
>   ~/Areas/Account/Views/Shared/ConfirmAccount.ascx
>   ~/Views/Account/ConfirmAccount.aspx
>   ~/Views/Account/ConfirmAccount.ascx ~/Views/Shared/ConfirmAccount.aspx
>   ~/Views/Shared/ConfirmAccount.ascx
>   ~/Areas/Account/Views/Account/Account.master
>   ~/Areas/Account/Views/Shared/Account.master
>   ~/Views/Account/Account.master ~/Views/Shared/Account.master
>   ~/Areas/Account/Views/Account/Account.cshtml
>   ~/Areas/Account/Views/Account/Account.vbhtml
>   ~/Areas/Account/Views/Shared/Account.cshtml
>   ~/Areas/Account/Views/Shared/Account.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Account/Account.cshtml ~/Views/Account/Account.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Account.cshtml ~/Views/Shared/Account.vbhtml

This is similar to the last one, where the first ones are the right path if it was looking for cshtml there, but for some reason it's not and I don't understand why. Where it looks for the cshtml pages it looks for account instead of ConfirmAccount.

How do I properly return the ConfirmAccount.cshtml view in the scenario where my model is a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass in a string as the only parameter, it's using the overload `View(string viewName)`.

You need to make sure you use the overload `View(object model)`.

You can do this by casting your model to an `object`.

```
return View((object)id);
```

I tend to avoid `string` models, specifically for this reason.

Make sure you look at all the overloads for `View` - for example: `string, string` is `viewName, masterName` where `string, object` is `viewName, model`, so in order to use that, you'd again have to cast to `object`. The overload for three parameters is `viewName, masterName, model`.

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't think of how to force it to use the object one, very simple solution.

Comment: Yep, it caught me off guard the first time I used a string model, drove me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

By default the `WebFormViewEngine` is included BEFORE the `RazorViewEngine`. That's why it's looking for *.aspx.

To fix it, tell the View Engine to look for Razor Views before WebForm Views by dropping the following code in your `Global.asax.cs`

```
protected void Application_Start() 
{ 
  ViewEngines.Engines.Clear(); 
  ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine()); 
  ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new WebFormViewEngine()); 
}
```

Comment: Although this does appear to change it so it looks for .cshtml first, and then .aspx, it still looks for each in the same locations, and the .cshtml are not the correct locations.